# PHP PDO how to reset/destroy a persistent connection

Tags: php, pdo

For my PHP website, I use a PDO database connection which is a persistent connection, because without that it can take ~30 seconds just to establish the connection. This works fine most of the time, however periodically network issues cause the persistent connection to "break" in such a way that all queries fail. Within PHP, how can I kill the connection and create a new one?

Simply destroying the connection does not do it, because that simply destroys the reference to the connection and then on reconnection, PHP just gets the same connection out of the cache.

Answer (score -4):

> how can I kill the connection and create a new one?

No.

> it can take ~30 seconds just to establish the connection.

set up your DNS properly or simply change localhost for 127.0.0.1